# Add to Contact Crashing on iPhone 5

Tags: iphone, ios6, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

I am using Appcelerator titanium sdk for saving contact on iPhone 5 and my app is working fine on iOS 5 and iOS 6 simulator but when I am running it on iPhone 5 (Physical device) and saving my contact onto phonebook and it is crashing. I am unable to figure out what is the problem as it is working perfectly fine on iPhone 4 and 4s devices and simulator.

```
    addBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){

    var isContactPresent = 'false';
    var people = Titanium.Contacts.getAllPeople();

    for (var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
        Ti.API.info("People object is: "+people[i]);


        var title = people[i].fullName;
        if (!title || title.length === 0) {
            title = "(no name)";
        }

        if (win_3.titleStr === title) {

            Ti.API.info('Address Book ' + title);
            Ti.API.info('Contacts to be added ' + win_3.titleStr);

            isContactPresent = 'true';

            var dialog = Ti.UI.createAlertDialog({
            message: 'Contact has already been added in Address Book',
            ok: 'Ok',
            title: 'Contacts Present'
            }).show();

            break;

        } 
    }

    if(isContactPresent == 'false') {
            SaveContacts();

            var dialog = Ti.UI.createAlertDialog({
            message: 'Contact has been added successfully',
            ok: 'Ok',
            title: 'Contacts Added'
            }).show();
    }

    //alert('Contact has been added successfully');
});

function SaveContacts() {

    Ti.API.info('Win Email ' + win_3.emailStr);
    Ti.API.info('Win Phone ' + win_3.phoneStr);


    var contact_type = "home";

    var contact = Titanium.Contacts.createPerson();

    contact.kind = Titanium.Contacts.CONTACTS_KIND_ORGANIZATION;
    contact_type = "work";
    contact.organization = win_3.titleStr;

    if (win_3.emailStr != ' ' || win_3.emailStr != '') {
        contact.email = {contact_type: [win_3.emailStr]};
    } else {

        win_3.emailStr = ' ';
        win_3.emailStr = 'Testing';
        contact.email = {contact_type: [win_3.emailStr]};
    }

    if (win_3.phoneStr != ' ' || win_3.phoneStr != '') {
        contact.phone = {contact_type: [win_3.phoneStr]};
    } else {

        win_3.phoneStr = ' ';
        win_3.phoneStr = '11231323';
        contact.phone = {contact_type: [win_3.phoneStr]};
    } 

    Titanium.Contacts.save();

}
```

Comment: Please post the debug log of the crash, this will tell us more then your code.

Answer (score 0):

iOs6 needs some contacts permissions for adding contact onto addressbook:

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/release-notes/?version=2.1.3.GA#ios_6

Comment: Permissions are allowed but contacts are not saving into address book